# Can I start a sentence with "i.e."?

Tags: sentence, abbreviations, latin, sentence-starts

While writing a rhetorical question I ran into a case where it seemed natural to start a sentence with "I.e":

> How do we handle the case when the list is empty? I.e., if the filter matched no entries?

Is that OK in this case?  In *any* case?

Edit: Thanks, everyone. It seems the consensus is that it's legal but not attractive. I like the alternatives presented in the accepted answer and comments. For my part, I will probably be avoiding the construct in the future.

Comment: I'd just suggest writing *How do we handle the case when the list is empty (i.e. the filter matched no entries)?*

Comment: @snumpy: Agreed. I don't suppose it makes sense to say you *can't* start a sentence with “i.e.” as if that were some basic rule of grammar. But unless I'm much mistaken you can't do it without unecessarily raising eyebrows. Your alternative is much better.

Comment: @snumpy that's indeed better... although I'm not sure the OP example is 100% wrong, like @Fumble said... But better choose the "I'm sure of it" alternative :D

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Same with "e.g." In theory, sure, you could lead a sentence off with the abbreviation, but the capitalized first letter is aesthetically displeasing.

Comment: @The Raven: I didn't want to come right out and say it, but - yeah - that capitalized first letter doesn't do it for me either.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28172/when-a-sentence-starts-with-e-g-should-the-e-be-capitalized

Comment: Since your sentence doesn't have a main verb, it will always look sloppy, no mater how it starts.

Comment: You always *can*. The question is whether you *may* or *should*.

Comment: I.e. a good question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Combo of my and @FumbleFingers' comments, which I believe would constitute an answer:

While one couldn't empirically insist that a sentence cannot begin with *i.e.*, doing so would unnecessarily raise some eyebrows.  Might I suggest a couple of alternatives?

> - How do we handle the case when the list is empty (i.e. the filter matched no entries)?
> - How do we handle the case when the list is empty, i.e. the filter matched no entries?

Comment: ... or, "How do we handle the case when the list is empty, i.e. the filter matched no entries"? The idea is that the "i.e." is an important but severable part of the idea, instead of its own thought.

Comment: @KeithS: Could I get away with "How do we handle the case when the list is empty - i.e. the filter matched no entries?" I know I'm overly fond of dashes - but we gotta use 'em up *somewhere*. While I'm at it, since my first sentence was a question within a question, could I have slipped another question mark in there? :)

Comment: +1 For KeithS's suggestion... most of the style guides I've bumped into over the years prefer this form.

Comment: I was under the impression that `i.e.` should be followed by a comma in most cases.

Comment: Regarding comma after i.e.: https://jakubmarian.com/comma-after-i-e-and-e-g/

Answer (score 10):

My view is that *i.e.* can usually be replaced with *that is to say*, so if you are prepared to start a sentence with "That is to say" then "I.e." should be OK too, and if not then not.

I think it is fine.

Comment: It's always less clumsy to use a well-structured english sentence, than to fall back on latin abbreviations.  I really think i.e. and e.g. go better in parenthetical remarks, an informal email, or footnotes, than the body of any written article, or essay.

Comment: `i.e.` is `id est` which literally means `that is`. **If it *can't* be replaced with "that is" then it is being used incorrectly.**

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a stylistic question more than a grammatical one.  Grammatically speaking, "i.e." isn't even true English, it's short for the Latin phrase "id est" (translation: "that is").  Some would say it's best to avoid non-English terms whenever possible, and it's certainly possible here by simply saying "that is."

Perhaps then the question becomes "Can I begin a sentence with 'That is?'"  And again, the grammatical answer is probably yes, but it still seems like sloppy style... at least to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that "i.e." is conjunctive, and therefore beginning a sentence with it would be poor style.  Certainly it would grate.  I'm not sure I could produce a grammatical rule to back this up - it just feels wrong.