# Entire sentence in parentheses

Tags: punctuation, parentheses

I am formatting a new book for my company and ran into a problem.

There is a sentence that reads:

> Before beginning, watch Part I in the DVD series, *God & the History of Art*.  (If available as part of your program.)

That the author wants me to change to:

> (Before beginning, watch Part I in the DVD series, *God & the History of Art*.  If available as part of your program.)

This sentence is one line, not part of a paragraph.

Is it right to surround an entire standalone sentence with parentheses?

Comment: Also see [question #13528](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13528/where-to-put-the-periods-when-using-a-parenthetical-sentence) and [question #37153](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37153/when-using-complete-sentences-in-parenthetical-e-g-or-i-e-situations-should-t)  and [question #61579](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61579/where-does-the-question-mark-go-inside-or-outside-the-parentheses)  and [question #72449](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72449) and [question #2119](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2119) as in Linked-Questions list

Comment: The "sentence" in parentheses isn't actually a sentence, so if you want to keep those words a better rendering is "Before...Art (if available...program)."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, provided it's all parenthetical material.

This appears to qualify. However, I'd make it all one sentence and add in the deleted *it* for clarity:

> (Before beginning, watch Part I of the DVD series *God & the History of Art*, if it is available as part of your program.)

Comment: 'for clarity' ... AND for syntactic well-formedness. 'If ...program.' is not a sentence.