# When using complete sentences in parenthetical e.g. or i.e. situations, should the first word be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, parentheses

In a bulleted list of very technical sentences, where each bulleted item has one or two parenthetical examples or restatements which are complete sentences, should the first letter of each e.g. or i.e. sentence be capitalized or not?

Example:

- Here is my technical sentence. (e.g., **S**hould the word of this example be capitalized like this?)
- Here is another technical sentence.  (i.e., **t**his really isn't an i.e., I just want to know if the first word should or should not be capitalized and am providing an example of yes and no.)

I originally posted this on English Language & Usage [When using complete sentences in parenthetical e.g. or i.e. situations, should the first word be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37153/when-using-complete-sentences-in-parenthetical-e-g-or-i-e-situations-should-th/37154#37154) and in discussion with @simchona the analogy of semicolon punctuation came up.  Here are the corresponding examples:

- "As we discussed, you will bring two items; a sleeping bag and a tent are not optional." - No doubt, the "a" in "... a sleeping..." should be lowercase.
- "As we discussed, you will bring two items. A sleeping bag and a tent are not optional." - No doubt, the "A" in "A sleeping ..." should be capitalized.
- "As we discussed, you will bring two items (i.e., a sleeping bag and a tent are not optional)." - no doubt, the "a" after the "i.e.," is lower case.
- "As we discussed, you will bring two items. (i.e., A/a sleeping bag and a tent are not optional)." - Now the sentence in parenthesis is standing alone, i.e., it's not embedded in the bulleted sentence.

Should the parenthetical in this example start with "(i.e., a sleeping ...) OR "(i.e., A sleeping ...)"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When using complete sentences in parenthetical e.g. or i.e. situations, should the first word be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37153/when-using-complete-sentences-in-parenthetical-e-g-or-i-e-situations-should-th)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I start a sentence with "i.e."?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30106/can-i-start-a-sentence-with-i-e)